# Why can't I get the left arrow to work?

Tags: xy-pic

```
$$
\xymatrix{\ar @{} [dr]
x[n] \ar[d] \ar[r]^-{DTFT} & X(e^{j\omega}) \ar[r]^-{Sample} & X(k) \ar[d] \\
  \ar[r]^-{\neq} & {x_1[n]} & {IDFT_N\{ X(k)\}} \ar{l}} 
$$
```

Produces this result:

[image: Result]

I simply want the arrow to point to the result and I have tried a few different things but it is simply not working. I got all of the from the manual btw... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: At the end of the last line you have `\ar{l}` where I would have expected `\ar[l]`; that is, you have braces instead of brackets.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `$$...$$`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/237192.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the code a bit and the end result should be what you wanted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{\ar @{} [dr]
x[n] \ar[d] \ar[r]^-{\mathrm{DTFT}} & X(e^{j\omega}) \ar[r]^-{\mathrm{Sample}} & X(k) \ar[d] \\
  \ar[r]^-{\neq} & {x_1[n]} \ar[r] & {\mathrm{IDFT}_N\{ X(k)\}}
  } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Drawing with the left arrow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{\ar @{} [dr]
x[n] \ar[d] \ar[r]^-{\mathrm{DTFT}} & X(e^{j\omega}) \ar[r]^-{\mathrm{Sample}} & X(k) \ar[d] \\
  \ar[r]^-{\neq} & {x_1[n]}  &\ar[l] {\mathrm{IDFT}_N\{ X(k)\}}
  } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]